# Purchased Logic Pro X not showing up in updates

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, upgrade, logic

I purchased Logic Pro X on the app store. It's never showing in the updates, I just realised I still had the 10.3.1 version and I cannot update it to 10.4.6.

I use Catalina, so the update should have been done automatically. How can I get it done?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot update it to 10.4.6"? Does the update not show in the store, does the download fail, or something else?

Comment: Did you use the AppleID that's currently signed in on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your Apple ID. Make sure that you are signed in using the same ID that you used to purchase the download.